# Divisions with prime cases of equations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For an ODD integer $x$

let us define $y^2 + 1 = (x + 2) (x^2 -2x + 4)$

is there any prime $p$ such that $p\mid(x^2 -2x + 4)$ or $p\mid(x+2)$ in order to   $ p|y^2 +1$

Comment: $y^2=x^3+7$ has no integral solutions. see [here](http://oeis.org/A054504).

Answer (score 1):

For given $x$, there is always a prime $p$ with $p\mid (x^2-2x+4)=(x-1)^2+3$, because otherwise $(x-1)^2+3=\pm 1$, which would mean $(x-1)^2=-2$ or $(x-1)^2=-4$; a contradiction.

The condition $p\mid (x-1)^2+3$ for some (odd) $x$ says that we have $(-3/p)=1$ for the Legendre symbol. So it is a necessary condition on the prime $p$ that $-3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

The equation $y^2+1=(x+2)(x^2-2x+4)$ defines an elliptic curve. We can rewrite it as
$$
y^2=x^3+7.
$$ 
This is a particular case of Mordell's equation. It has no integral solutions, see [here](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEQQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgradnumthy%2Fmordelleqn1.pdf&ei=Q2ghVLOcDMaEOKqggdAK&usg=AFQjCNExJsQ8bikneg2KeVVzvOH_vwlctQ&bvm=bv.75775273,d.ZWU).
It has been discussed also already at an earlier question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942489/not-a-perfect-square-of-the-form-for-any-integer-x).